# Crystal Reports 64 bit

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, web-deployment, 32bit-64bit

Here's a question.  We've just upgraded from Crystal 2008 to Crystal 2020.  Crystal 2008 is 32 Bit, Crystal 2020 is 64 Bit.  When we develop a report using the Crystal Reports Designer we're using a 64 Bit application.

When we include the report in a C# Webforms App created in Visual Studio (which is still a 32 Bit App) and deploy it to an IIS Server (64 Bit) what bitwise structure is Crystal using to produce the report from the server given that the project has a number of Crystal Libraries included as part of that deployment. For the project to compile those CR Libraries have to be 32 bit.  How does the webserver run the report in 64 bit or is it running in 32 bit WOW mode?

Comment: _"IIS Server (64 Bit) ...How does the webserver run the report in 64 bit or is it running in 32 bit WOW mode"_ - Just because IIS is 64-bit doesn't mean a website is.  Check your sites App Pool to see whether **32 bit apps are allowed**

Answer (score 1):

The Crystal runtime has 32-bit as well as 64-bit versions.
It is up to you to select one of these targets when compiling.
And up to you to to deploy the matching Crystal runtime (32-bit or 64-bit).
You also need to ensure the machine has a matching database connectivity (e.g. 32-bit or 64-bit ODBC DSN).